# Mesh only visible as an outline with In Front mode?

Tags: modeling

[image]

So I am attempting my first proper retopology of a sculpted head I created, and I am attempting to set my plane to "In front" in the viewport display settings, but then whenever I'm in solid mode in the viewport, it has this outline instead of a solid view. Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Are you doing this through the object properties? If so, there should be a box that says "display as". Set it to "solid" or "textured" - just not "wire" or "bounds".

Comment: Yes, I've got it as "textured" and it still does this. Changing it to "solid" does the exact same thing, and changing it to "wire" or "bounds" makes the head in the back solid but keeps the plane the same as it appears in the image.

Comment: Strange. It should be solid then, even if the wire-frame box is checked. Is this 2.83?.... 2.90? Maybe try the same thing using an earlier version and see if it works there.

Comment: It's 2.83, I just switched to 2.82 and the problem was solved! Thank you! That's strange, I wonder if this is an actual bug or just something on my end?

Comment: I know of 2.83 has a few hiccups that are planned to be fixed in the official 2.9 release. Whether this is related, I'm not sure. You might want to look into it specifically, and if no-one's reported the same, you could file a bug report. But yeah, generally when something doesn't work in one version, but works perfectly fine in the previous version, it's pretty safe to assume it's some kind of bug. Many of the non-bug issues I'm aware of in 2.83 stem from the need to update graphics drivers, or are caused by using a very old (10+ years) unsupported GPU.